# ReactJS - execute a javascript code after the ajax function renders the data

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Where should I place the JavaScript code, so that I can call a plugin after the render is completed.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/3.2.2/es6-promise.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.2.1/react-dom.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.13.1/axios.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="root"></div>


  <script type="text/babel">

    const REST_API = 'users.json';

// The root component
const App = props => (
  <div className="app">
      <UserListContainer />
   </div>
);

// Container
class UserListContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [{
        name: 'Loading data...'
      }]
    };
  }

  loadData() {
    axios.get(REST_API).then((response) => {
      //console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({
        users: response.data
      })
    });
  }

  // Life cycles hooks
  // facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html
  componentWillMount() {};
  componentDidMount() {
    // Data is loaded async, therefore will be inserted after first DOM rendering
    this.loadData();
  };
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {};
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return true;
  };
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {};
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {};
  componentWillUnmount() {};

  render() {
    return (<UserList users={this.state.users} />);
  };
}

// Presentation
const UserItem = (user, index) => (
  <li key={index}>
          <div className="header"> 
            <div className="name"> {user.name}</div>

            <div className="index">{(index+1)}</div>
          </div>

            <div className="date">
            <i className="fa fa-date" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span>{user.date}</span>
          </div>



          <div className="contact">
            <i className="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span>{user.phone}</span>
          </div>
      </li>
);
const UserList = props => (
  <div className="user-list">
    <h1>React ES6 Ajax, Container and Presentation - example</h1>
    <ul>
        {props.users.map(UserItem)}
     </ul>
   </div>
);

// Render
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.getElementById('root')
);

    </script>



</body>

</html>
```

I added it to

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    alert();
  };
```

Then , after the first element, the alert function is working,

These are my actual files - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G7UOaCFS_521hfZc4-jNeLGiKR4XaQjP?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then the `componentDidUpdate()` hook would be the correct hook to use to access the DOM (and call your plugin). This will be called after your component has rendered.

As [state in the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) for `componentDidUpdate()`:

> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

A key thing to note is that the `componentDidUpdate()` hook does not fire for the first render.

**Update**

To address this "first render" issue, you could make use of the optional callback that can be passed to `setState(state, callback)`. This `callback` is fired after your component is rendered (following state change).

In your case, you could do something like this:

```
loadData() {
    axios.get(REST_API).then((response) => {
      //console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({ users: response.data }, () => {

           // When this callback is invoked, the component has been 
           // rendered and the DOM can be safely accessed
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have updated the question please check, is there any way to run it after, all the elements are rendered

Comment: fires after the first element rendering, I would like to have it fired,after all of them renders.

Comment: @ArunPrasadES I've just updated the answer - does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is the correct place to fetch data and you're doing it right way. `componentDidUpdate` hook is used if you need to receive the props or state and update accordingly. This is required if your child component is going to update them from the parent component by receiving the data. But after looking into your code, I din't notice that you're requiring parent component. So, you don't need `componentDidUpdate` hook. You just need to do as of follows.

Maintain the state like:

```
this.state = {
  users: [],
  loading: true,
  loadingText: 'Loading data...'
};
```

Then, after you fetch the data set loading to false:

```
loadData() {
    axios.get(REST_API).then((response) => {
      //console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({
        users: response.data,
        loading: false
      })
    });
  }
```

Now, when you render them:

```
const UserList = props => (
  <div className="user-list">
    <h1>React ES6 Ajax, Container and Presentation - example</h1>
    <ul>
        {!props.loading && props.users && props.users.map(UserItem)}
     </ul>
   </div>
);
```

Notice: You have to pass the loading state as well.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: what's your exact problem?

Comment: @This is my actual file, I just need to attach a plugin to the rendered items after all the elements are rendered - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G7UOaCFS_521hfZc4-jNeLGiKR4XaQjP?usp=sharing    Plugin is not included, I need to know the exact place where to initialize the plugin, after the rendering is complete

Comment: how are you including the component?

Comment: I am following a tutorial, new to this.

Comment: where are you including? in the update hook? you need to include in the render itself.